# Problems with Params

Tags: reactjs, axios, mern

I am having an issue when I click on a post that is pulled from database, access by the slug in the title with LINK, then click on it and this happens.

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: you are trying to access to the property that does not exist. first make sure match have property called params and then use axios to fetch your result.

Answer (score 0):

the problem isn't in the component in the image attached, it's with the parent component where you send the match, match doesn't have a property called params

Comment: What do you suggest to fix it?